# Switching between cases in commands

Tags: macros

The following shows the use of `\IfStrEqCase{#1}{`.  But I have also found `\str_case:nn`.  Which would be the most preferable to switch between cases ?

Although familiar with `expl3` I am confused about on the appropriate expl3 one to use from

```
\str_case:nn
\str_case:nnTF
\str_case:Nn
\str_case:NnTF
```

The `TF` imply that the command includes true and false branches (which I might not use).

`\str_case:Nn` seems to state that a local variable containing the text will be used.  Would `#1` constitute a local variable ?

Here is one implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Product}{O{direct} m m}{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        {direct}{#2 \times  #3}%
        {tensor}{#2 \otimes #3}%
    }[%
        Unsupported: #1.
    ]%
}

\begin{document}
$\Product{a}{b}$

$\Product[direct]{a}{b}$

$\Product[tensor]{a}{b}$

$\Product[wacky]{a}{b}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\str_case:` if you are familiar with `expl3`.

Comment: `\IfStrEqCase` is provided by `xstring`. `\str_case:nn` et al are part of the `expl3` programming layer. If you aren't sure which of the `expl3` control sequences to use, sticking to the `xstring` version is probably wise. If you were familiar with `expl3`, you wouldn't need to ask which of them to use. As has been explained to you before, the part following the colon is the argument specification. This is explained in `interface3` and you've been given numerous examples, as well as directions to tutorials. Which is best depends on the context.

Comment: Why have you created yet another account?

Comment: As before, I would answer if you used an account which can reasonably be expected to survive til dawn. Karl is, unfortunately, not such an account.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `\str_case:nnF`, which is quite like a drop-in replacement of `\IfStrEqCase`.

In the documentation of `expl3`, you find

```
\str_eq:nnTF
```

(with *`TF`* underlined), which means that `T` or `F` (or both) can be omitted.

Of course you also need to enter the `expl3` environment, so

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Product}{O{direct} m m}
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {% allowed strings and actions
        {direct}{#2 \times  #3}
        {tensor}{#2 \otimes #3}
      }
      {% string not recognized
        Unsupported:~#1
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```